# Get() and Dataframes with R

Tags: r, variables, naming

This might be a dumb question, but I can't seem to find a solution. I have the following lines of code

```
name1 <- paste("pred.return.Tr", trainInt, ".Te", testInt, sep = "")
assign(name1, as.data.frame(matrix(, dim(dfVar[1])-NullR, 3, TRUE)))
```

So now that I have my df created and it's name stored in name1 I am trying to manipulate value and metrics of the data frame. Their are two things I need to do but can't see how. First is to change the column names and second is to have value inputed. I was thinking the following but I get the error could not find function "get<-";

```
colnames(get(name1)) <- c("Return", "GrossReturn", "CummReturn")
get(name1)[1,1] <- some value
```

Appreciate the help, pretty sure there is a simple solution. I just can't think of one for some damn reason. I'm new to coding so don't be harsh

Comment: My usual advice in these cases is to keep your data frames in named lists, not isolated in your workspace. Then things are quite simple, and there's generally no need for `assign` or `get`. But people sometimes really don't like that advice.

Comment: I agree with joran. Especially if you are new to coding, this is a bad habit to get in to. This is not usually how you approach this problem in R (it's more common with, say, SAS). It's better if you describe the problem you are really wring to solve rather than trying to make this particular solution work.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you **really** want to do this you have to use incantations involving `eval()`, `substitute()`, `as.symbol` ... however, as the comments suggest, this is extremely awkward because it's non-idiomatic R.

```
name1 <- "junk"
assign(name1, data.frame(1:3,1:3,1:3))

eval(substitute(colnames(n) <- c("Return", "GrossReturn", "CummReturn"),
           list(n=as.symbol(name1))))
eval(substitute(n[1,1] <- 14,
           list(n=as.symbol(name1))))
```

There might be a *slightly* more direct way to do this (I'm not very good at `eval()` etc.), but it probably can't be done much more easily.

If you instead put your data frames into a list (if you're trying to use this sort of indirect addressing, presumably you have a lot of them ...), then all of this becomes easy.  For example:

```
myStuff <- list(junk=junk)
names(myStuff)  ## "junk"
```

To set column names or values:

```
colnames(myStuff[[name1]]) <- c("a","b","c")
myStuff[[name1]][1,1] <- 57
```

If you have more than one data frame, you can either put them in the list at the beginning:

```
myStuff <- list(junk=junk,junk2=junk)
```

or add them on the fly

```
myStuff[["junk3"]] <- junk
```

Actually, it occurs to me that there is a very hacky way to do this, which is to treat your global environment as a sort of list (actually it's an `environment`, but it can be indexed in the same way as a list ...

```
colnames(.GlobalEnv[[name1]]) <- c("d","e","f")
.GlobalEnv[[name1]][1,1] <- 64
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this actually helps a ton. Just a quick question since I haven't used this. How exactly do you create list with multiple data frames, or how do you add data frames to the list?